# Dynamic component with bindings

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Let's say I got an app that is made up of an app bar and a content area, the content area is my `<router-outlet>` and a typical URL will look something like

```
/department/4/employee/5/sales
```

which would display the sales of employee #5 from department #4 in the content area. At the same time I'd like to display the employee's picture and name in the app bar, if I change the route, app bar and content area should reflect that change.

Now here's the catch. The app bar does not always show picture and name but may use a different template altogether, e.g. if I navigate to settings

```
/settings
```

there is no department or employee information so in this case the app bar should only state "Settings."

I'm having trouble coming up with a working solution, I tried dynamic component loading, passing the employee's data along but that turned out to be a one-trick pony, because once the item is rendered there is no binding to the employee data left.

I considered auxiliary routes, but somehow doubt this will actually get me anywhere.

Can this be done at all?

Comment: I can't make much sense of your question. Maybe this is what you're looking for https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: In a nutshell, I need a dynamic template for the content displayed in the app bar, which at the same time will reflect route changes. I've tried all sorts of services and events and it isn't pretty.